# std::map - Element access without exception and without insertion

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a recurrent pattern with the use of std::map.

I want to retrieve the value only when the key is present, otherwise I don't want to insert element. Currently I'm using `count(key)` or `find(key)` (which one is better? from the documentation the complexity seems to be the same) and if them returns a positive value that I access the map. However I would like to avoid the use of two operations on the map. Something like:

```
map<string, int> myMap;
int returnvalue;
boole result = myMap.get("key1",returnValue)
if(result){
  \\ use returnValue
}
```

Reading the std::map documentation on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) I found two functions for accessing map elements:

- [at()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/): which throws an excpetion if the key is not present
- [[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D): which insert a new value if the key is not present

None of them satisfy my necessity.

Comment: Why would you avoid `std::map::find`??

Comment: @billz No reason, I forgot that find returns an iterator.

Comment: Pro tip: Avoid cplusplus.com - use https://cppreference.com/ instead - cplusplus.com is chuck full of bad advice and incorrect information - cppreference.com is much higher quality.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find):

```
auto it = myMap.find(key);

if (it != myMap.end())
{
    // use it->second
}
else
{
    // not found
}
```

This part was easy. The harder problem is when you want to look up if an element exists and return it if it does, but otherwise insert a new element at that key, all without searching the map twice. For that you need to use `lower_bound` followed by hinted insertion.

Answer (score 0):

using `count()` for sure the key is exists
then uses `find()` to get the k/v pair

```
if (myMap.count(key))
{
    auto it = myMap.find(key)
}
else
{
// not found
}
```

Comment: That's bad advice.  Use `find` to determine whether the element exists, and if it does, use the iterator it returned to access the element.  There's no point in doing the look up twice (and I've yet to find a reasonable use for `std::map<>::count`).

Comment: This is not very efficient. Use Kerrek's answer instead.

Comment: `count` is also not good practice if you want to extend this idea to multimaps, since you'll potentially be counting a large number, when all you wanted to know if the number is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, could use `contains` to check whether element exist.