# C++ std::map adds values when key not found

Tags: c++, insert, null, operator-keyword, stdmap

I'm not very good with collections in C++ so go easy on me if my question is a bit Stupid.

I'm currently having 2 maps

```
map<int, Segment*> varSeg;
map<Segment*, bool> rules;
```

So varSeg is filled with an assignment of var -> Segment* objects and based on some logic I'm trying to fill in the rules map using something like the following loop.

```
for(...looping on some vars){
    int segVar = getVar();
    rules[varSeg[segVar]] = (segVar > 0);
}
```

However, if a certain `segVar` wasn't already contained in `varSeg` I encountered a weird behavior. A new entry was created inside `varSeg` map with key `segVar` and a value of `Null` for the Segment. Which ofcourse caused all sorts of problems in my code later.

My question is why did this happen? isn't the `varSeg[segVar]` statement here a read statement? This was very difficult to debug because I couldn't find a place in my code I was writing null values to the map. So could you explain what I did wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::map - Element access without exception and without insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290780/stdmap-element-access-without-exception-and-without-insertion)

Comment: What did you expect the value of `varSeg[segVar]` to be if it *didn't* add anything to the map?

Comment: Actually I did check for it in my code, however due to a small bug the value could sometimes be changed to negative value after checking and then it was when searching for it it would add a -ve key mapped to null.

Comment: c++11 has a function called `const T& at( const Key& key )` that does what you probably expected of `operator[]`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why did this happen?

Because that’s what `std::map::operator[]` is supposed to do, as clearly stated in the documentation.

If you don’t want this (mostly useful) behaviour, use the `find` member function instead of `[]`.

At any rate, your code would fail even if `[]` didn’t create a new element (or if you used `find`) since you simply don’t handle the case where `segVar` isn’t found in `varSeg`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). The case is handled in my code actually however I accidentally changed the value of 'segVar' to negative and that caused the problem. And it was so weird seeing that reading values are creating nulls. Now I understand thanks.